# Struts2 subgrid post extra parameter while expanding

Tags: jquery, struts2, jqgrid

I am using Struts2 grid. I want to send one javascript object and rowId while reloading the subgrid. The code I used is as below. I call the following function on onSubGridRowExpanded

```
    $.subscribe('subgridExpanded', function(event, data) {
    var rowId =  event.originalEvent.row_id;

    var pData = {
                    'sId' : rowId, 
                    'sJSONStr' : sJsonList  // sJsonList is javascript global variable
                   };


     $("#packageSubGrid").jqGrid('clearGridData').jqGrid('setGridParam',
            { 
                datatype: 'local',
                page : 1,
                postData: pData,
                data:data.packageSubList
            }).trigger("reloadGrid");  

});
```

I am not able to reload the subgrid. The method on server side is getting called but parameters are going as null. 
My grid code in struts2 is as below

```
 <s:url id="shipmentUrl" action="getGrid" />
                <sjg:grid id="shipmentGrid" href="%{shipmentUrl}"   dataType="json"
                caption="S Details" gridModel="shipmentList" requestType="post"
                formIds="mForm" multiboxonly="true" multiselect="true"
                multiselectWidth="50" onSelectAllTopics="onSelectAll"
                rowList="100,500,1000" pager="true" sortorder="desc"
                navigator="true" navigatorSearch="false" navigatorAdd="false" navigatorEdit="false" navigatorDelete="false"  
                rowNum="1000" rownumbers="false" gridview="false" onSubGridRowExpanded="subgridExpanded"
                >

         //subgrid code
                    <s:url id="packageSubUrl" action="getSubGrid"  />
                    <sjg:grid id="packageSubGrid" subGridUrl="%{packageSubUrl}" dataType="json" 
                             sortorder="desc" cssStyle="float: left;" requestType="post" gridview="true" 
                             gridModel="packageSubList"
                             footerrow="false"
                             userDataOnFooter="false"  onGridCompleteTopics="subGridComplete" >

                            <sjg:gridColumn name="pId" index="pId" id="pId"
                                title="P Id" align="center" sortable="false" width="110" />
                            <sjg:gridColumn name="pName" index="pName" id="pName" title="P Name"
                                align="center" sortable="false" width="110" />

                    </sjg:grid>         


                <sjg:gridColumn name="sName" index="sName"
                    id="sName" title="S Name" align="center"
                    sortable="true" width="105" />

                <sjg:gridColumn name="sId" index="sId" 
                    id="sId" title="S"  key="true" />
    </sjg:grid>
```

So my problem is I am not able to find anything in Struts2 about how to post extra parameter with subgrid apart from id. So I was trying to use the jqgrid methods to do it but pData is going as null at server side and also I am not able to reload subgrid with `data.packageSubList` by using `setGridParam` which usually works with normal grids.

Comment: I'm not use Struts2 myself, but I suppose that you should use `jqGridSubGridRowExpanded` instead of `$.subscribe('subgridExpanded'` to implement subgrid. You don't posted any details which subgrid you need to created and where to load the data for the subgrid. I just see that the code which you use can't work. Could you provide more details about what you need to implement.

Comment: @Oleg I have added more details about the code